# The connection is not found error in auth0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, auth0

I am using auth0 to maintain users details. and I am following [This article](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-owin/02-login-custom).

I downloaded project which is using default lock screen, and it's working fine, I am able to create user and login, logout.

When I try with custom login view, and when I try to login with my credentials, It's giving me error "The connection is not found".

I am not sure, Which connection I need to pass here.

Below is the code which I paste from mentioned article.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    AuthenticationApiClient client =
                        new AuthenticationApiClient(
                            new Uri($"https://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"]}/"));

                    var result = await client.AuthenticateAsync(new AuthenticationRequest
                    {
                        ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"],
                        Scope = "openid",
                        Connection = "Database-Connection", // Specify the correct name of your DB connection
                        Username = vm.EmailAddress,
                        Password = vm.Password
                    });

                    // Get user info from token
                    var user = await client.GetTokenInfoAsync(result.IdToken);

                    // Create claims principal
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName ?? user.Email),
                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string")
                }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                    // Sign user into cookie middleware
                    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, claimsIdentity);

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
                }
            }

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Below is Error I am getting,

[image: Error Details]

I am passing correct connection name in AuthenticationRequest also as below image,

[image: Connection name]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `Connection` name specified in the `AuthenticationRequest` instance that you pass into `AuthenticateAsync` maps to an existing database connection within your Auth0 account.

More specifically, you're currently passing `"Database-Connection"`as the name of the connection and you need to ensure that either a connection with that name exists or change your code:

```
new AuthenticationRequest {
    // ...
    Connection = "Database-Connection",
    Username = vm.EmailAddress,
    Password = vm.Password
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am passing database name "Auth0AuthenticationDB" and it's allowing me log in, but it's not giving me Token information now. I was getting token when I was using Lock screen

Comment: Working.. I pass token in claimsIdentity on Login action